# Using the cryptogen for Production environment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have question related to cryptogen and hyperledger fabric network setup. I want to explain my workflow. I wanna know this procedure can be used for production

```
1. I have 2organisation org1,org2.In which each organisation consist two peers,only one ordered for 
   both organisation and 2 fabric-ca server.
2. Generating the all the key pairs using the cryptogen tool using the crypto-config.yaml.
3. Generating genesis block and channel transaction using the configtx tool with configtx.yaml. 
4. (Important Note:)I am using the CA private key and certificate ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem, which is generated using the cryptogen tool in my network docker yaml file to setup the fabric ca.
5. After setup all i am running the network its works fine.
6. I am enrolling and registering the admin and user from the outside using the fabricnodesdk.
```

here its good practice to use the cryptogen generate ca private key and certificate to setup and run the CA server in production. If this not good practice, Is there any other way i can implement it. Please your suggestion would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric docs suggest not to use cryptogen tool for production environment

**Reason**: it’s a tool and all crypto materials are generated on the fly with 10 years validity and you cannot control further with fabric-CA like revoke, reenroll, etc  because fabric-ca will not have a copy in the database

Traditional way: generating crypto material with fabric-CA by registering and enrolling an identity with 1-year validity

But if you take my opinion, I have used cryptogen tool 2 years back in one production environment. There is no harm to use cryptogen tool in production unless you will need to interact with CA to make changes to the identities. It depends on the use case in our usecase we do not need to keep changing the identities it was fixed forever it was a typical usecase

> But later and now I have been using **fabric-CA** and **custom CA** to
>   generate crypto materials leveraging more possibilities

Comment: thank you for your replay. But incase for starting i use the cryptogen, later i can updated with fabric-ca is it possible ?

Comment: Once you create you cannot change the whole consortium crypto and you don’t need to change but you can continue with fabric-CA

Comment: may i can get any example or demo code for using fabric ca in production environment, and i observer if i used the node js to interact with fabric ca,it will create the wallet folder not msp structure. Is there any example to create the folder structure using fabric node js with fabric ca similar to cryptogen folder structure.

Comment: That’s for user crypto, but for entities msp you should understand the structure of the msp and generate the certificates accordingly all you need to do is surprise the wallet and make enrolment output as plain data so that you can use for network

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to use fabric-ca?

Comment: fabric-ca official docs are the best if you are coming from programming background then it should be enough

Answer (score 1):

I find it a dirty way to do it. Your Fabric-CA is working and your orderers and peers are of course working because their certificates are correct and have been suitably signed by the CA. But the fact is that the identities corresponding to the orderers, peers and clients that you generated via cryptogen have not been registered in the Fabric-CA database, so you can neither manage nor revoke those identities and their corresponding certificates via your Fabric-CA in the future.

My advice (for production environments, of course):  Don't be lazy; take care of a good proper `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` and `fabric-ca-client-config.yaml` configuration; launch safely your Fabric-CA; and script your initial identity registration, certificate enrollment and MSP/TLS folder structure creation.

Comment: Yes if you try to revoke or do any operation it will give error no rows in result set if crypto is generated using cryptogen tool